# Using Google Maps in Commercial Apps

Tags: google-maps, licensing

I am starting to develop an extension that I want to **sell**.
It requires Google Maps Javascript API which requires a APIKEY.

Do I just include Google Maps logic and tell the buyer to get their own api key here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key and insert it in the settings. Would rather use Google even if it has its own branding.

Otherwise I was thinking of just using http://leafletjs.com/  because it is open source/free?.

I noticed other people selling plugins with Google Maps included and they don’t seem to have a key. How do they do this, is this allowed.

Thoughts?

What is the Standard with this type of thing?

Answer (score 0):

The API key is now required. Before June 22, 2016 it was optional, but now you have to use it always.

Please have a look at this post for more details:
https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.es/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html

You can implement the plugin with settings where the customer adds his API key.

However, you should be aware that for several types of applications Google Maps API requires a Premium plan license. For example, asset tracking or intranet solutions may be used only with the Premium plan API key. Otherwise the Standard plan is allowed.

Please have a look at restrictions section of ToS to understand when the customer requires a Premium plan license:

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions

Comment: Thanks, for insight !!